# Terraform Error: Error locking state: Error acquiring the state lock: 2 errors occurred:

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform0.12+

I tried terraform versions v0.12.26 and v0.13.3. Both failed.

terraform plan

Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...

Error: Error locking state: Error acquiring the state lock: 2 errors occurred:
* ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found
* ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found

Terraform acquires a state lock to protect the state from being written
by multiple users at the same time. Please resolve the issue above and try
again. For most commands, you can disable locking with the "-lock=false"
flag, but this is not recommended.

Related source code:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    encrypt        = false
    bucket         = "dev-terraform-state"
    key            = "dev/Oregon/eks/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-west-2"
    dynamodb_table = "dev-lock-table"
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.12.0"
}
```

Comment: Hi. I've noticed that you have bunch of questions with answers, but not a single one was accepted. It is a good practice to accept questions which were helpful as it help others in future with similar issue. If good answers are not accepted, it prompts people to make duplicate questions with the false assumption that the answers given weren't userful.

Comment: I would like to accept those answers. But, how to accept?

Comment: Under upvote/downvote buttons there is a "tick" symbol.

Comment: I found out dev-lock-table is not created in AWS dynamodb table  by running terraform init and plan. But, why is it not created?

Comment: I removed the line, dynamodb_table = "dev-lock-table". Then, "terraform plan"  works. Why?

Comment: because you're no longer locking with dynamodb at all.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The error is `ResourceNotFoundException`, which suggests that your `dev-lock-table` does not exist.

Terraform does not create it. Instead it **must exist before** you will use it. From [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html):

> dynamodb_table field to an **existing** DynamoDB table name.

Comment: any one coming in from Google, ensure you created the table in the region specified in the provider config

Comment: The table needs primary key as LockID

Comment: Thanks @chris that was happening with me and your message cleared out my issue! appreciate it

Comment: If i manually delete the lock from dynamodb would it break anything ?

Comment: @astroanu Please make sure new question for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It remains to create the table to work, so it will be able to save the state.

[image]

IAM

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran `terraform force-unlock <LOCK_ID>` (docs) to delete the lock.

Lots of discussion [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/14513)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the table created and region specified in below code are same

terraform { backend "s3" { bucket = "" key = "" region = "us-east-1" dynamodb_table =

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're using the same AWS account and correct region. DynamoDB Table must be in the same region as CLI/SDK configuration

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error message after I modified my backend.tfvars file and then tried to run `terraform plan`. To fix it, I reinitialized the IaC:

```
terraform init -backend-config=backend.tfvars
```

which generated another error message that instructed me to migrate the existing state:

```
terraform init -backend-config=backend.tfvars -migrate-state
```

Migrating the existing state allowed the backend to reconfigure successfully, and I could then run `terraform plan`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the particular environment Access & Security Credentials.

And also if your profile is set as default make sure you are running the terraform apply for that particular account or you might need to configure the keys again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, as I took forked it from some other repo which operates in some other AWS account, I was having the wrong dynamodb_table.
I updated the the dynamodb_table field in my backend config, then it worked fine.

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    key = <VALID_KEY_NAME>
    region = 'eu-central-1'
    dynamodb_table = <A table which exists>
    encrypt = true
  }
}
```

This is my problem, you may check if the table exists in dynamodb already or not.

Answer (score 0):

Issue: **AWS S3 with Dynamodb backend**
IF got such error Error loading state: failed to lock s3 state: 2 errors occurred:
* operation error DynamoDB: PutItem, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, api error ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key LockId in the item

Error loading state: failed to lock s3 state: 2 errors occurred:
* operation error DynamoDB: PutItem, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, api error ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key LockId in the item

Solution is: while creation bucket i have primary LockId insteand LockID after fix such my issue resolved. Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).